# Spacemacs not using the theme for tooltips after resizing the window

Tags: themes, spacemacs, tooltip

I'm using Spacemacs with Solarized dark theme on Arch linux using i3wm, and I'm having some issues with tooltips. If I open Emacs so it only covers part of the screen, the tooltips shows up with the correct font, colors and size. If I fullscreen Emacs (and optionally make it smaller again), the tooltips seems to revert to some standard X11 theme with a black background, white text and very small font (I'm on a HiDPI display). Changing theme and back doesn't revert the correct tooltip theme.

Any idea what is wrong here and how I might fix it? I don't know what information would be useful, and I'm totally new on Emacs.

Comment: Do you know of any other applications that do this as well? Emacs uses regular system tooltips, and I can't think of a reason that it would be messing them up.

Comment: Haven't seen any yet, not even with applications that is using plain X11 (no GTK/QT/.. but themed too).